# Removing <legend> and <fieldset> from FormHelper in CakePHP

Tags: forms, cakephp, html-select

I'm making some practice with `CakePHP`, and I'd like to remove `HTML` elements I usually avoid like `<legend>` and `<fieldset>` from the forms I create from `Form->create()`.
I've saw there is some way like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', 
    array (
        'action' => 'login',
        'inputDefaults' => array (
            'fieldset' => false,
            'legend' => false
        )
    ));

    echo $this->Form->inputs(array (
        /*'legend' => __('Login', true),*/
        'username',
        'password'
    ));

    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

If I write this `<legend>` and `<fieldset>` will be visible instead.
Does exist some specific option to remove them?

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="/site.com/users/login" method="post" id="UserLoginForm">
    <div style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>
    <!-- hoto to remove this --><fieldset><legend>New User</legend><!-- end of removing -->
        <div class="input text required">
            <label for="UserUsername">Username</label><input type="text" id="UserUsername" maxlength="255" name="data[User][username]">
        </div>
        <div class="input password required"><label for="UserPassword">Password</label><input type="password" id="UserPassword" name="data[User][password]"></div>
    <!-- hoto to remove this --></fieldset><!-- end of removing -->
    <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Accedi"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was

```
echo $this->Form->inputs(array (
    /*'legend' => __('Login', true),*/
    'username',
    'password'
));
```

used instead of

```
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
```

from the examples I've read on [book.cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/)

Answer (score 4):

the inputs() function is new to 1.3 and allows you to bundle your fields in a single function and tidy things up a little.  Here's how to kill the fieldset and legend:

```
echo $this->Form->input(array(
    'legend' => false,
    'fieldset' => false,
    'username',
    'password'
));
```

Comment: +1 You must use both options ` 'legend' => false, 'fieldset' => false,` together to get rid of fieldset tags.

Answer (score 0):

I've never ever seen form helper generate `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`. This will be part of your view. A typical view file (/app/views/items.ctp)

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Item');?>
    <fieldset> <!-- remove this from your view (CTP) file -->
        <legend><?php __('Add Item'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('item_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
```

As you can see, `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` are part of the HTML in the view. Simply remove it from the markup. The FormHelper only generates the markup for the FORM and a few utility inputs.

Comment: I have't wrote any part of html in the view. The view is exactly how appears in the first part of code of the question.

Comment: Are you using scaffolding? Also remove all the options arrays that you have (inputDefaults...) Just use clean input(). What happens?